# Making code not runnable on other platforms

Tags: swift2, availability

In Swift 2, how can I use the `#available` condition to prevent a block of code from executing on a certain platform? The `*` seems to allow the version you specify in your deployment target. And specifying `iOS Int.max` doesn't work.

Comment: So you only want code to execute on any version of iOS, but not at all on OSX? or something like that?

Comment: @Ian Yes, that is what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#available` is used for specifying certain versions on certain platforms. If you only want to limit your code to a certain platform, you can use compiler directives.

```
#if os(iOS)
    // do stuff only on iOS
#elseif os(OSX)
    // do stuff only on OS X
#endif
```

But I believe the reason what you were trying to do with `Int.max` wasn't working because it requires an `UInt32` literal (i.e. up to 4294967295 which is (2^32) - 1 or UInt32.max -1):

```
if #available(iOS 1000, watchOS 1000, *) {
    // Should execute only on OSX higher than deployment target
} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at syntax for availability checking in swift 2.0

```
if #available(platform name version, ..., *) {
  statements to execute if the APIs are available
} else {
  fallback statements to execute if the APIs are unavailable
}
```